Name of a movie where a marriage counselor narrates her life story to a client
I once watched this movie that starts with a woman visiting a marriage counselor who narrates her life story to the client
This lady got a job at some place and a guy finally convinced her of being unfaithful to her husband. 
She left her husband for a drunkard and it ends with something like her former husband saving her from the guy after she was wounded.
Please remind me the name of this movie. I want to watch it again.

Hi. Do you remember the year of release? The country\language? The actors? Where\when did you see it?

I don't remember those things. But i recall it had something like 'diary' on its title. i thought it was doctor's diary, but this wasn't a series.

I finally found it. It is Tyler Perry's "Temptation: Confessions of a Marriage Counselor" from 2013... in case someone is looking for it.

An ambitious married woman's temptation by a handsome billionaire leads to betrayal, recklessness, and forever alters the course of her life.


Thanks. They say i can accept it in two days. I will do that.

@user3196949: Just a reminder -- you should be able to accept it now :)
